# Best Practice: Adding packages to Journal Latex Template

Tags: packages, journal-publishing

I am using the INFORMS style file (https://www.informs.org/Find-Research-Publications/INFORMS-Journals/Author-Portal/LaTeX-Style-Files) .

I need to write a algorithm and I found that the algorithm package is not included as a part of the style file and I wanted to use it.

I could not find anything on the INFORMS webpage on adding additional packages. What is the usual policy for journal submissions? Should I just go ahead and add the package to my latex file?

Comment: You'll have to contact them to be certain. I've helped prepare submissions where the guidelines explicitly said "no extra packages", but when I asked about a few relatively common packages, they said those were allowed. If the package you want to use has a long history, and you're not using features added recently, you're probably safe.

Comment: This is a good question, since it's very common. However, may solicit opinionated answers... in my opinion. Perhaps we should make it CW so it can grow (over time) with answers from authors who have submitted to different journals...?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Werner Even if an answer here concerned just the right journal and just the right package, the person would still have to ask because production processes and policies change over time. The information here would be difficult to maintain and in danger of suggesting people didn't need to (a) check the journal instructions for authors, and (b) ask the journal for clarification if necessary.

Comment: @cfr: Excellent point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for the journal office.